# How to make only specific column resize in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a DataGridView and I want only a specific column to resize when the window is resized.

Currently, I am resizing the columns which need to be fixed on form_Load() and form_Resize()

```
dataGrid1.Columns[0].Width = 100;
dataGrid1.Columns[1].Width = 100;
dataGrid1.Columns[3].Width = 100;
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [`AutoSizeMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.autosizemode.aspx) property on the `DataGridViewColumn` class.

I'd imagine you want to set it to [`DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnmode.aspx) on columns 0, 1 and 3, and to `.Fill` on column 2. (It looks like `.None` means it won't even adjust to the cell contents, which I don't think is what you want.)